# WebStorm short writing example needed

Tags: html, css, webstorm

I've heard that WebStorm (JetBrains IDE) provides a short writing syntax for html-grids. Something like `div.class.class.class#id` but I can't find a documentation for that.

Could you give a short example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Emmet. WebStorm supports such abbreviation expansion.

- http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/emmet-support.html?search=emmet

WebStorm has own implementation and does not support all Emmet features/actions .. but abbreviation expansion is supported.